# EasyMock verify method called and execute method

Tags: java, easymock

I have a method returning `void` and I know how to verify if the method has been called:

```
MyValidator validator = createMock(MyValidator.class);      
expect(validator.validate());
replay(validator);
classUnderTest.submit(); //this will call validator.validate()
verify(validator);
```

But I also want the real method MyValidator.validate() to be executed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but [andDelegateTo()](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html#andDelegateTo%28java.lang.Object%29) seems to be exactly what you want:

```
MyValidator realValidator = new MyValidator();
MyValidator mockedValidator = createMock(MyValidator.class);
expect(mockedValidator.validate()).andDelegateTo(realValidator);
```